# Passing variable outside ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please help - I have the following code which returns the variable 'results' in an alert. I want to use this variable outside of the function, and cannot get a callback, or outside declaration to work successfully. I'm sure I'm being a muppet, so I apologise for this basic question.....

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script>

$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'https://creator.zoho.com/api/json/my-company-culture/view/PageFeed_Report?scope=creatorapi&authtoken=d670dc68ac0f6d7ca389e7b206a25045',
        success: function (results) {
            var raw_result=JSON.stringify(results);
            alert(results);
        }
    });
});

 </script>
```

Comment: Can we see your callbacks that do not work?

Comment: Have you tried declaring the success function outside of $.ajax?

Comment: `"POST"` and `"jsonp"` should never be in the same call to `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 6):

The jQuery 1.5+ way of resolving this is by using deferred objects:

```
var res;

var ajax = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: ...
}).done(function(results) {
    // you may safely use results here
    res = results;
    ...
});

// you cannot safely use 'res' here, only in code
// invoked via a 'done' callback on the `$.ajax` promise

console.log(res);    // undefined
```

It would be incorrect to attempt to copy `results` into some other variable in the outer scope unless you have ensured that no other code tries to access that variable until the AJAX call has completed.

Comment: This works, and looks a whole lot neater than my original code, but I don't know how to use the 'results' variable elsewhere in my script.

Comment: @MarkE the whole point is that you _can't_!  If other stuff depends on `results`, it needs to be passed as a parameter to a function called from within the callback.  Alternatively you need to arrange that whatever code will use that value cannot possibly be invoked until after the `.done` callback has been completed.

Comment: I know this in not clean - but I fixed my problem by using the results to populate and open a new page - recovering the variables from the URL in the same way as using post. It did exactly what I needed it to do in this form - and I couldn't have done it without all the help. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Alnitak, you have no idea what this answer means to me! For some reason I also had to set async=false to get the results appended to the div.

Comment: @nawissor read the top answer on the question that's linked above as a duplicate: "How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?"

Answer (score 3):

Well, why not:

```
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
    <script>
    function do_the_stuff(smth) {
         console.log(smth);//or do whatever you want to do with this data
    }
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: 'https://creator.zoho.com/api/json/my-company-culture/view/PageFeed_Report?scope=creatorapi&authtoken=d670dc68ac0f6d7ca389e7b206a25045',
            success: function (results) {
                var raw_result=JSON.stringify(results);
                do_the_stuff(results);
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

That works fine for me. I don't see any problem.

Comment: If I change console.log(smth); to alert(smth); I simply get 'object Object'......

Comment: So change it to 'alert(JSON.stringify(smth))' OR pass 'raw_result' instead of 'results' to function.